# Get WIFI to work without internet connection?

Tags: wifi

I wonder if someone can help me to get the WIFI to work while no having Internet connection?  Is there a way to install the missing drivers from the Live/Flash USB from which I installed the OS?  (I'm running a 2009 MacBook Retina.)  Thanks.

Comment: Can I confirm the model? There was no “Retina” anything until the iPhone4 was released in June 2010 

Comment: Sorry 2009 was just a guess...  I know it's the first or second Retina model.  I have the eOS installed and don't know anymore where that info is stored!

Comment: A more basic question is how to get eOS to install all the required drivers?  I don't have experience with it, but I'm thinking (naively) as when one install some OS X version.  I know the drivers are included in the this Live/Flash USB, but I need to track down all dependencies...